# Python Pandas doesn't support .append function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I am trying to create dataframe through webscript by following code**

```
`population_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Rank", "Country", "Population", "Area", "Density"])

for row in tables[table_index].tbody.find_all('tr'):
    col = row.find_all('td')
    if (col != []):
        rank = col[0].text
        country = col[1].text
        population = col[2].text.strip()
        area = col[3].text.strip()
        density = col[4].text.strip()
        population_data = population_data.append({"Rank":rank, "Country":country, "Population":population, "Area":area, "Density": density}, ignore_index=True)

print(population_data)`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbYuf.png)
A table similar to the img is expected. It prompt **AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'. Did you mean: '_append'?** error. What is the problem with my code?

Comment: "What is the problem with my code?" - well, the code says `population_data.append`, and the error points at this, and tells you that `population_data` is a `DataFrame` (which I assume you already knew), and that `DataFrame`s do not have a `append` method, therefore you cannot use `population_data.append` as there is nothing with that name for you to use. What exactly was unclear about it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for your reply. As pandas 2.0 doesn't support **.append**, I used **._append** instead. It works.